# VS2010 extension, OptionPage, readout values

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I'm currently writing an editor margin using the new VSX MEF extension framework. I didn't found a counterpart for the VSPackage-OptionPage stuff and I'm therefore using the old framework for the settings.

Now I face the problem to readout the settings values from within a MEF component. I can't call GetDialogPage() from there. Is it a good idea to have code like this:

```
public static MyPackage Instance;
public MyPackage () { Instance = this; } // Hopefully called only once?

public bool MyBoolOption { get { var opts = GetDialogPage(...) as ...; return opts.MyBoolOption; } }
```

I am not sure if this is "clean" code.

Even more problematic is to inform my MEF components that something has changed. E.g. what to do in OnApply() to inform a MEF component "Hey, it's time to update because XYZ has changed!".

How to do that in a clean way?

Best regards,
D.R.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put `[Export]` attribute on your package class (MyPackage), and then import it in your MEF component using [Import]:

```
[Export]
public class MyPackage : Package
{
}

[Export]
public class EditorExtension
{
    [Import]
    private MyPackage package = null;
}
```

You can also have events on your package when properties change or OnApply is called.

Comment: Are you sure that MEF isn't creating a new object of MyPackage instead of using the existing one created by Visual Studio?

Comment: Actually you might be right. In this case, in your package, you can get at the MEF composition container and manually call ComponentModel.GetService<>() to get to a shared MEF-composed type. It will be imported from the Editor Extension and the same instance would be shared by the package.

Comment: Thank you. Do you know how I can mark your comment as valid answer?

Comment: Just mark the original answer as answer and upvote if you like :)